# jQuery change td: color with multiple statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have simple html table, if td tag contains words "hour" and "day" I want set color to red. I did it with one statement:

`$("td:contains('hour')").css("color", "red");`

I want include the word "day", I tried next:

1. `$("td:contains('hour') && td:contains('day')").css("color", "red");`
2. if ($("td:contains('hour')") && ($"td:contains('day')"))
                       {
                           css("color", "red");
                       }

How I can do it ?

Comment: Please provide sample html as per [mcve]. Then explain the last `&&` while referencing the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.For matching multiple words you have use `contains` again.

```
   $("td:contains('hour'):contains('day')").css("color", "red");
```

Example

```js
  $("p:contains('is'):contains('name')").css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>My name is Donald.</p><!--it will matched contains both `is` and `name`-->
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p><!--not matched -->
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p><!--not matched contains only `is`-->
```

Comment: I was typing the same thing, but you beat me to it

Comment: Thank you it works, also how I can write next (if it contains day and not contains hour) ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hekmat Excellent, Thank you very much, I will accept your question in 15 min.

Answer (score 0):

You need to further refine the selector after finding the first match and be aware of the case-sensitive nature of your test (only lower-case matches will be found).

```js
$("td:contains('hour'):contains('day')").css("color", "red");
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hour</td>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>hour</td>
    <td>day</td>
    <td>None</td>
    <td>hour and day</td>
    <td>Hour and Day</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For a case-insensitive search:

```js
var theCells = $("td");

// Loop through the cells and check lower-case text against lower-case value
theCells.each(function(){ 
  if(this.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf("hour") > -1 &&
     this.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf("day") > -1){
       this.style.color = "red";
  }
});
```

```css
table, td { border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hour</td>
    <td>Day</td>
    <td>None</td>
    <td>hour and day</td>
    <td>Hour and Day</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```